# How to copy multiple Excel Worksheets to a new Workbook simultaneously using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

There is plenty on Stack Overflow (and the wider internet) about copying multiple Excel Worksheets to a new Workbook by doing so in a Worksheet-by-Worksheet loop; BUT is there any way to do it in a single operation, e.g. via a Collection or similar?

I ask because if your Worksheets have cross-sheet links, these get messed up when copying them (I do not want to move the sheets, but copy) sequentially i.e. you end up with a mess of links pointing back to the original source file; whereas I need a subset of Worksheets correctly cross-linked to each other, but simply moved to a new Workbook (where I can drop all the VBA code elements and some helper sheets that need to be missing from the final document).

Can I do something like build an Array with the Worksheets I want, and then do Worksheets(myarray).Copy or similar? What I am asking is patently possible doing it by hand in the GUI, but I am aware this is no guarantee of a VBA method to do the same.

Comment: It would help if you could show us what specific problem you ran into with your attempt.

Comment: `Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")).Copy` should do the trick

Comment: @braX, there was no specific 'problem' other than the one I mentioned i.e. if you have sheets A and B, where B has links to A, then when you copy A and then B (sequentially), the copied sheet B still links to the original sheet A, not the copy.

Answer (score 0):

I stick with the Workbook.SaveAs method. I always make a fresh copy of the file when preparing to send it out to end users. This eliminates the worry of the sheets not pointing to the new Workbook and then I systematically drop anything else that isn't needed on the end result.

Comment: I would also often do this, but in this case, the user needed to be in control of where the 'exported' new file should go - and given it could be local/network/Sharepoint, I avoided the pain of automatically saving to those different options by leaving the new workbook unsaved for the user to deal with. I would also need to remove more code from the Save As workbook (ThisWorkbook and modules), so a little more clunky in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @FunThomas's suggestion, I did a bit of tinkering and got the following to work:

```
Dim sheets_to_copy() As String, wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, shp As Shape, vbcomp As Object, i As Long
    
    ' First, loop through sheets and determine which ones to copy
    i = 0
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Not (Left(ws.CodeName, 3) = "JM_") Then
            i = i + 1: ReDim Preserve sheets_to_copy(1 To i): sheets_to_copy(i) = ws.Name
        End If
    Next ws
    ' Copy the array of sheets
    Worksheets(sheets_to_copy).Copy
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook ' Find the newly created Workbook object
    
    ' Tidy up the copied-out sheets
    On Error GoTo err_handler
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        With ws.UsedRange
            .ClearComments
            .Font.ColorIndex = 1    ' Make cells black
        End With
        For Each shp In ws.Shapes
            shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbBlack
        Next shp
    Next ws
    
    ' Remove code bits
    For Each vbcomp In wb.VBProject.VBComponents
        With wb.VBProject.VBComponents(vbcomp.Name).CodeModule: .DeleteLines 1, .CountOfLines: End With
    Next vbcomp
    Set wb = Nothing
    Exit Sub
err_handler:
    Resume Next
```

Note that I use a CodeName prefix on the (fixed in my case) sheets to identify them for ignoring in the first loop, where I build an array of Strings (sheet names to copy).
I then do Worksheets.Copy as suggested (thanks FunThomas) to get a new Workbook, which I then grab and set as wb.
Finally I can tidy up the copied sheets (format to black, remove comments, and then a final loop to purge sheet-level VBA code).
Note: I need the error handler because of my loop over the Shapes collection, as not all of them are Text Boxes, so I get an error referring to the TextFrame2 member.